# 0MQ req wait for rep in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

I'm new to javascript, Node.js, and 0MQ, so n00b * 3 here.

I want to set up a simple request and reply, but I want the client to wait for a response before sending out the next request.

The [zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc10) goes over this, but the [Node.js](http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:hwclient) version does not behave like the [C](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:hwclient) version (which is what I want).

I realize I'm butting up against a paradigm shift here in how I look at the problem, but I still feel like I should be able to do this. Can I make a `recv` call (or something similar) in the client?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by client should have to wait for a response before next request? If you're talking about HTTP request, you should keep in mind that HTTP requests, regardless of platform/language, are stateless. If you just want to ensure the same client doesn't send two requests before getting a reply to the first, just filter the requests using IP/origin/cookie (i.e: any way to distinguish clients).

Comment: I'm using this for inter-process communications. Specifically, I have one process collecting data and it wants to pull data from another process before sending the aggregated data out over the network. I do not want to send the data out of the network until I hear back from the other process and I have all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the node.js version of ZMQ doesn't behave the way you would expect it to if you're coming from the C version, but it actually *is* behaving according to the rules, it's just adding in a bit of its own sauce to the mix.

Specifically, the C bindings will throw an error if you try to break the strict REQ/REP/REQ/REP cycle. In node.js, it will cache the out-of-order message until the previous response comes back, and *then* send out that new message... so you're still getting REQ/REP/REQ/REP, in order, and you can choose to send a message whenever you want without an error.

This is probably a poor design choice on the part of the node ZMQ binding authors, first of all because it's confusing to new users such as yourself, and second of all if you're using REQ/REP you'd probably prefer a hard failure if you go out of order, otherwise you'd be using a different socket type.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/259#issuecomment-30026059) the conversation I had on the node ZMQ binding page where I figured this out, it may provide some extra context.